# Containers in pod won't talk to each other in Kubernetes

Tags: django, docker, kubernetes, redis

I have three containers in a pod: nginx, redis, custom django app.  It seems like none of them talk to each other with kubernetes.  In docker compose they do but I can't use docker compose in production.

The django container gets this error:
[2022-06-20 21:45:49,420: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://redis:6379/0: Error 111 connecting to redis:6379. Connection refused..
Trying again in 32.00 seconds... (16/100)

and the nginx container starts but never shows any traffic.  Trying to connect to localhost:8000 gets no reply.

Any idea whats wrong with my yml file?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: djangonetwork
spec:
  ingress:
    - from:
        - podSelector:
            matchLabels:
              io.kompose.network/djangonetwork: "true"
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.network/djangonetwork: "true"
---
apiVersion: v1
data:
  DB_HOST: db
  DB_NAME: django_db
  DB_PASSWORD: password
  DB_PORT: "5432"
  DB_USER: user
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: web
  name: envs--django
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: web
  name: web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: web
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        io.kompose.network/djangonetwork: "true"
        io.kompose.service: web
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: nginx:alpine
          name: nginxcontainer
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
        - image: redis:alpine
          name: rediscontainer
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
          resources: {}
        - env:
            - name: DB_HOST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  key: DB_HOST
                  name: envs--django
            - name: DB_NAME
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  key: DB_NAME
                  name: envs--django
            - name: DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  key: DB_PASSWORD
                  name: envs--django
            - name: DB_PORT
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  key: DB_PORT
                  name: envs--django
            - name: DB_USER
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  key: DB_USER
                  name: envs--django
          image: localhost:5000/integration/web:latest
          name: djangocontainer
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: web
  name: web
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "8000"
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: web
```

Answer (score 0):

You've put all three containers into a single Pod.  That's usually not the preferred approach: it means you can't restart one of the containers without restarting all of them (any update to your application code requires discarding your Redis cache) and you can't individually scale the component parts (if you need five replicas of your application, do you also need five reverse proxies and can you usefully use five Redises?).

Instead, a preferred approach is to split these into three separate Deployments (or possibly use a StatefulSet for Redis with persistence).  Each has a corresponding Service, and then those Service names can be used as DNS names.

A very minimal example for Redis could look like:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        service: web
        component: redis
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redis
          ports:
            - name: redis
              containerPort: 6379
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis # <-- this name will be a DNS name
spec:
  selector: # matches the template: { metadata: { labels: } }
    service: web
    component: redis
  ports:
    - name: redis
      port: 6379
      targetPort: redis # matches a containerPorts: [{ name: }]
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
spec:
  ...
    env:
      - name: REDIS_HOST
        value: redis # matches the Service
```

If all three parts are in the same Pod, then the Service can't really distinguish which part it's talking to.  In principle, between these containers, they share a network namespace and need to talk to each other as `localhost`; the `containers: [{ name: }]` have no practical effect.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense thank you, I will use your example to try and clean it up further.